# Using Pyserial to read and write data

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to understand how Pyserial is interfacing with my windows machine. I am using this basic code from the pyserial website.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM1')  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         # check which port was really useds
ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string
ser.close()          # close port
```

I am using python 2.7 and IDLE as the IDE for this code, I am wondering should I be able to read the string hello from my console after I run the code? My output as of right now only show COM1, while not printing hello to my console. Is the hello message being sent to my COM1 port? If so, how would I be able to read the message I sent?

Also as a bonus question, I sometimes randomly have this error happen to me.
SerialException: could not open port 'COM1': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.'). Sometimes when I re-run the code it goes away, other times I have to restart my computer. I appreciate any help, thanks.

COM1 is not connected to anything currently.

Comment: Are you expecting that writing to COM1 will write to the terminal / console?   (It won't). You write to a serial port to communicate with something connected to that port. If nothing is connected, how are you expecting to read back your string? What are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should open the connection first with `ser.open()`. You can write the command like you are doing, but to read it, you need to use `ser.readlines()`. Then you can close the connection. [This](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) page has a lot of good info! What is connected to the COM1 port?

Comment: Nothing is currently connected